# sorting array have error with none english key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

i have an array like this
i have to sort it by value

**(the array key are non English!)**

```
Array
(
    [مدیرکل] => 2
    [پیش] => 2
    [بینی] => 2
    [و] => 33
    [هشدار] => 2
    [سریع] => 2
    [سازمان] => 2
    [هواشناسی] => 2
    [از] => 7
    [آغاز] => 1
    [بارش] => 10
    [برف] => 7
    [باران] => 4
    [در] => 10
    [پایتخت] => 1
    [طی] => 4
    [24] => 1
    [ساعت] => 1
    [آینده] => 3
    [خبر] => 1
    [داد] => 1
    [احد] => 1
    [وظیفه] => 3
    [با] => 5
)
```

33 must be at first and 24 and 10 and 7 and etc
but when i use `sort` or `asort` or `uksort` it just return 1 !!!

```
1
```

is there any problem with these function and array with non English language as key!?

code:

```
$nextArray = array_count_values($arr1);
$nextArray = sort($nextArray);

print_r($nextArray);
```

Comment: `*sort` functions return `bool`, not `arrays`. Did you know that?

Comment: no!but print_r after it dont return any thing!

Comment: you can read [docs](http://it2.php.net/sort) about sorts in php; then, consider you maybe need to [set the locale](http://it2.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) to obtain the expected sort

Comment: what's the exact code you use to sort and print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, let's see:

```
$nextArray = array_count_values($arr1);   // this is an array
$nextArray = sort($nextArray);            // as *sort function return bool you overwrite array value with bool value

print_r($nextArray);
```

The proper code should be:

```
$nextArray = array_count_values($arr1);
sort($nextArray);
print_r($nextArray);
```